# Elasticsearch - Remove double results in search

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't know how to remove double results with the same value in one field.

My Searchquery:

```
query :{
         range : {
                    "endtime" : {
                        "lt" : "2017-02-09T20:00:00",
                        "gt" : "2017-02-09T01:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
```

In my results there's one field called "link" which has often the same value (f.ex. https://www.facebook.com).

I would prefer a solution for my query, that would be great.

Thanks.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
      "range" : {
          "endtime" : {
            "gte" : "2017-02-09T20:00:00",
            "lt" :  "2017-02-09T01:00:00"
          }
      }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

something like this.